# Was the "Do So" movement orchestrated by Cambridge Analytica and is it responsible for the results of the Trinidad and Tobago election?

Tags: politics, social-media, propaganda

[The Great Hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Hack) is a documentary which, among other things, claims that [SCL Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCL_Group) (which the now-infamous Cambridge Analytica is a subsidiary of) worked for the United National Congress (UNC) in Trinidad and Tobago and successfully helped them win the 2010 general election.

[This clip from the movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omc-5zj70M0) is purportedly a sales pitch that Cambridge Analytica at one point used that claims they are responsible for creating a movement called "Do So" which encouraged young people not to vote. However, searching for any additional information about this now just results in articles citing the movie itself.

Was there really a movement called "Do So" that encouraged young people not to vote in the 2010 Trinidad and Tobago general election? Could this really have swayed the vote in UNC's favour, as the video claims? Is there any evidence that UNC or Cambridge Analytica had anything to do with this movement?

Answer (score -1):

According to Trinidad and Tobago Police Service, *there is no independent evidence* of a "Do So" movement or Cambridge Analytica involvement in the election. Consequently, as far as we know, the 2010 T&T general election was not swayed by any such action.

> The criminal investigation into the Cambridge Analytica scandal and its involvement in an alleged breach of data privacy laws in Trinidad and Tobago is now closed....
> Deputy Commissioner of Police Jayson Forde said the matter was investigated but their best attempts to reach data analyst and author Christopher Wylie were unsuccessful....
> "In light of that, as far as we are concerned we are stumped and as such the TTPS is closing this investigation pending the emergence of evidence to support the investigations.” ....

https://www.guardian.co.tt/news/absent-witness-cambridge-analytica-case-closed-6.2.1111975.cd33be962e

Comment: I don't see anything in that article denying the existence of "Do So".  It just says that the T&T police were unable to get anywhere in investigating whether CA accessed citizens' data illegally, so they gave up.

Comment: While I'm not (usually) a conspiracy theorist, I would posit: if CA did create a "do so" movement, and it helped bring the UNC into power in T&T, then what the T&T Police say about an investigation might be suspect; after all, they work for that government.